# How to get a post content from another wordpress blog/site?

Tags: posts, multisite, feed

I have a situation where i need to display posts from a specific category from another wordpress site into my wordpress site.

Both are my sites and i thought of creating a page specially for this in site A and calling them through iframe in site B.

I thought another way of fetching them feed.. But i dont know how to fetch feed contents from other wordpress and how to create a feed for a specific category.

Comment: Are you talking about multisite environment or two seprate installs here?

Comment: Two separate installs

Comment: Check out this link for code samples to get post from WordPress to WordPress. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/38551/load-custom-post-type-in-a-different-wordpress-installation/38557#38557

Comment: Content duplication is bad for SEO at least add the meta tag: http://www.seobythesea.com/2010/11/google-on-duplicate-content-filtering-and-news-attribution-metatags/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of parsing the RSS feed, you could query the second blog directly with the builtin XML-RPC webservices, described in this [Question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16119/wordpress-as-xml-rpc-client).

Comment: Actually in my case i didn't want to have posts on both wordpress database.. I just want to display one random post from a specific category from Site A.

Comment: You don't have to "sync" the posts like discribed in the above question. But you could just query the second blog with XML-RPC. Use the XML-RPC client on site A, query site B and return your random post.

Answer (score 1):

I think RSS is a great option here.

To get a feed for a specific category, you simply add /feed/ to the end of the URL (or if you don't use permalinks, add ?feed=rss2 or &feed=rss2).

@Nickiler linked to a great post on getting RSS content: [Load custom post type in a different WordPress installation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/38551/load-custom-post-type-in-a-different-wordpress-installation/38557#38557)